# Picture tag in html works fine with Mozilla firefox but stucks on Google chrome

Tags: html, image, responsive-design

here is my simple code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>photo stock</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <picture>
           <source type="image/webp" media="(min-width: 601px)" srcset="3.webp" />
           <source type="image/webp" media="(max-width: 600px)" srcset="4.webp" />
           <source type="image/jpg" media="(min-width: 601px)" srcset="2.jpg" />
           <source type="image/jpg" media="(max-width: 600px)" srcset="1.jpg" />
           <img src="5.jpg" alt="RadWolf, Inc." />
        </picture>

    </body>
</html>
```

it works fine with firefox, but when it comes to Google chrome, it keeps showing me only first picture(3.webp) no matter how I resize the window.

is there any resolution for this one?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution by myself.

Note 1. In google chrome you should resize the window itself. instead I was using ctrl+shift+i and devise toolbar, responsive functionality.

2. in head section we should add

> < meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

so the final and working result is like :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>photo stock</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <picture>
           <source type="image/webp" media="(min-width: 1100px)" srcset="3.webp" />
           <source type="image/jpg" media="(min-width: 1100px)" srcset="2.jpg" />
           
           
           <source type="image/webp" media="(min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 1099px)" srcset="4.webp" />
           <source type="image/jpg" media="(min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 1099px)" srcset="1.jpg" /> 
           <img src="5.jpg" alt="RadWolf, Inc." style="width:300px;"/>
        </picture>

    </body>
</html>
```